# java сравнить строки с словами в разной поледовательности

Tags: java, android, строки, сравнение, множества

Подскажите как сравнить две или более строк с разной последовательностью слов?
строки:
MIKHAIL VLADISLAV GRIGORY
VLADISLAV MIKHAIL GRIGORY
IVAN ILYA VLADIMIR
ANDREY VLADIMIR ILYA
VLADIMIR IVAN ANDREY
Результат - 2 совпадения

Comment: так ничего не понятно, выделите каждую строку в кавычки, пожалуйста

Comment: "MIKHAIL VLADISLAV GRIGORY"   
"VLADISLAV MIKHAIL GRIGORY"   
"IVAN ILYA VLADIMIR"   
"ANDREY VLADIMIR ILYA"   
"VLADIMIR IVAN ANDREY"

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас напишу код, и отправлю как ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Может подскажете куда копать? Просто ума не приложу что тут применить.

Comment: Ну я думаю можно попробовать разделить строчку по пробелу, отсортировать массив, ну и сравнивать эти массивы.

Comment: Если Вам был дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простейшая реализация:

```
public boolean compare(String first, String second) {
    return Arrays.equals(getWordsSortedArray(first), getWordsSortedArray(second));
}

private String[] getWordsSortedArray(String text) {
    return Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Попробуйте, возможно для ваших задач не подойдёт, тогда можно улучшить. Тут слова разделяются просто пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую